# What does "make a rare return appearance" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can somebody explain "makes a rare return appearance" in this context for me, please?

> In all likelihood, yes, said Damien Courvalin, head of energy research for the Goldman Sachs’s global investment research commodities team. Mr. Courvalin **makes a rare return appearance** this year, after pretty much nailing it in his forecast for 2016. Last year he predicted further weakness in oil prices, followed by a recovery by the year’s end — which is just what happened.

Source: https://www.nytimes.com/2017/01/05/business/economy/financial-predictions-2017.html?_r=0

Answer (score 1):

**To make an appearance:** "To be present at an event (especially when you are there only briefly)." It is used figuratively in this case; Mr Courvalin is present in their list of investors and market experts, not at a physical event.

**To make a rare appearance:** "To be present at an event, when this is not something you do often."

**To make a return appearance:** "To appear at an event that you have appeared at before." Mr Courvalin is in the 2017 edition of the list, after also appearing in the 2016 edition.

**To make a rare return appearance:** This may have two meanings, although they are so similar in meaning that it doesn't really matter which is correct...

1. A *return* appearance is rare for Mr Courvalin.
2. *Any* appearance is rare for Mr Courvalin (so a return appearance would be especially rare).

Answer (score 0):

Rare because his appearance is rare. So, it's a return appearance, in context of his last year's appearance.

Answer (score 0):

He was on the list of the advisors who were right last year, and he is only the list this year, so he is making a "return appearance".  Return appearances on this list are rare (because the financial-advice business is a racket -- being right is pure luck, so it's unusual for the same person to be right two years in a row).